# Ezjail network in aws ec2 instance

Tags: freebsd, amazon-ec2, jails

I am trying to connect a jail to the internet in a aws ec2 instance. I am able to create the jail and execute a console inside, the problem is that the jail does not have any connection to the outside.

This are the steps to create the jail:

```
echo 'cloned_interfaces="lo1"' >> /etc/rc.conf
service netif cloneup
ezjail-admin create jail 'lo1|127.0.1.1,xn0|172.31.36.57'
cp /etc/resolv.conf /usr/jails/jail/etc
ezjail-admin console -f jail
```

After that if I try any installation using pkg:

```
The package management tool is not yet installed on your system.
Do you want to fetch and install it now? [y/N]: y
Bootstrapping pkg from pkg+http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/FreeBSD:12:amd64/quarterly, please wait...
pkg: Error fetching http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/FreeBSD:12:amd64/quarterly/Latest/pkg.txz: No address record
Address resolution failed for http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/FreeBSD:12:amd64/quarterly.
Consider changing PACKAGESITE.
```

See output of the host ifconfig:

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
    options=680003<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,LINKSTATE,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
    groups: lo
    nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
xn0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 9001
    options=503<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,LRO>
    ether 06:26:aa:da:23:d2
    inet6 fe80::426:aaff:feda:23d2%xn0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x2
    inet 172.31.36.56 netmask 0xfffff000 broadcast 172.31.47.255
    inet 172.31.36.57 netmask 0xffffffff broadcast 172.31.36.57
    media: Ethernet manual
    status: active
    nd6 options=23<PERFORMNUD,ACCEPT_RTADV,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
lo1: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
    options=680003<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,LINKSTATE,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
    inet6 fe80::1%lo1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x3
    inet 127.0.1.1 netmask 0xffffffff
    groups: lo
    nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
```

I think the second IP i give to the interface is not valid.

Do you know what would be the way to get connectivity from the jail?

Comment: Figure out how you want to route first. `lo1` with `127.0.1.1` is internal - so you would typically use pf to NAT traffic to the jail. The 2nd IP address confuses me. Maybe what you are looking for is `ip4=inherit`. Figure out addressing. Read [Chapter 15](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/jails/) and maybe [my previous jails answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/547971/74393). Then update Q.

Answer (score 0):

Got the connectivity working using pf

```
ext_if="xn0"
jail_net="127.0.1.1"
nat pass on $ext_if from $jail_net to any -> $ext_if
pass out
pass in
```

Comment: This adds NAT without filtering and passes all traffic. You waste CPU cycles without any benefit. A much simpler solution would then be to set `ipv4=inherit` in `/etc/jails.conf` and skip `pf`. I do not want to downvote as it is technically correct but I hope nobody copies this verbatim. [NAT in itself](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8772/how-important-is-nat-as-a-security-layer) should not be used as a "firewall".  You should use a `block` rule if that is what you are attempting.

Comment: I am pretty new to jails and server administration in general. Since I am managing the jail with ezjail, I cannot find the /etc/jails.conf file. Do you know what would be the equivalent for ezjail?

Comment: Do not add interface or IP when creating the jail. Add/change config file something like this: `export jail_name_parameters="ip6=inherit ip4=inherit"`. [The config file /usr/local/etc/ezjail.conf (copy the sample from /usr/local/etc/ezjail.conf.sample) and the per-jail config files under /usr/local/etc/ezjail/ (those are created automatically with the jails and managed by the ezjail-admin config command)](https://erdgeist.org/arts/software/ezjail/#slow-start). But again I find it easier just using plain [jail.conf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/547971/74393)